# SQLite query to delete a row doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a problem with deleting rows from a table. It should be pretty simple but I can't figure out why it's not working. This is my table creation:

```
database.execSQL(
    "CREATE TABLE " +PERSONAL_LIST_EXERCISES_TABLE +" (" +
    PERSONAL_LIST_ID +" INT, " +
    EXERCISE_ID +" INT);");
```

I try to delete a row by using this query:

```
    db.rawQuery(
            "DELETE FROM " +PERSONAL_LIST_EXERCISES_TABLE +
            " WHERE " +EXERCISE_ID +" LIKE '" +String.valueOf(exerciseId) +"'" +
            " AND " +PERSONAL_LIST_ID +" LIKE '" +String.valueOf(listId) +"'", null);
```

And I also tried using the delete method:

```
db.delete(
    PERSONAL_LIST_EXERCISES_TABLE, EXERCISE_ID +" =? AND " +PERSONAL_LIST_ID +" =? ",
    new String[] {String.valueOf(exerciseId), String.valueOf(listId) });
```

Both don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Already tested. I get the ids from the db, cache them in the listview items and use them to identify the respective row in the db.

Comment: @KayJ doesnt like statment require `%`

Comment: Why do you use 'LIKE' refering to an exact int? Change 'LIKE' to the equals operator.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the mistake, try with this:

```
db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM " + PERSONAL_LIST_EXERCISES_TABLE +
" WHERE " + EXERCISE_ID + " LIKE " + String.valueOf(exerciseId) +
        " AND " + PERSONAL_LIST_ID + " LIKE " + String.valueOf(listId) , null);
```

or this

```
db.delete(
PERSONAL_LIST_EXERCISES_TABLE, EXERCISE_ID +" = ? AND " +PERSONAL_LIST_ID +" = ? ",
new String[] {String.valueOf(exerciseId), String.valueOf(listId) });
```

the only changes i did were put spaces and quit ( ' )

And also try putting the "%" character on the LIKE sentence

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential issues.

1) When you use the LIKE function, you typically will use a wildcard (%).  Otherwise you might as well use =

Assuming you mean the EXERCISE_ID should have the String.valueOf(exerciseId) somewhere inside, I'd rewrite that part of the query like this:

```
LIKE '%" +String.valueOf(exerciseId) +"%'"
```

2) It's a little weird writing SQL code this way because you have on one hand the string that you're sending to the SQLLite database, and that string will have variables that represent fields.  On the other hand you have a string that you're assigning to the function, and the variables there represent fields in your Android application.

What it looks like you're doing here is referencing multiple fields in Android but none in SQL.  You haven't gived details, but assuming that EXERCISE_ID is a field in your database, the first line of the WHERE clause might read like this:

```
" WHERE EXERCISE_ID LIKE '" +String.valueOf(exerciseId) +"'" +
```

You see how I put EXERCISE_ID back into the string so it gets sent to SQLLite as-is?

If these two assumptions are correct, I'd rewrite your full statement like this:

```
db.rawQuery(
        "DELETE FROM " +PERSONAL_LIST_EXERCISES_TABLE +
        " WHERE EXERCISE_ID LIKE '%" +String.valueOf(exerciseId) +"%'" +
        " AND PERSONAL_LIST_ID LIKE '%" +String.valueOf(listId) +"%'", null);
```

Comment: 1. `LIKE` is not what I was looking for. I need to use `=`

2. In the first code block of my question you can see that `EXERCISE_ID` is a table column that takes `INT` as values. So putting it in `""` will result in an error since the string value is different from the string name. This is my definition: `public static final String EXERCISE_ID = "exercise_id";`

Answer (score 0):

And maybe you need to change to the next statement

```
db.delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

where:

```
db is your database
table is your table
whereClause is your where sentence
whereArgs are the arguments for your sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

It's finally working... The delete code written in my question is working completely fine (`db.delete(...)`). The `rawQuery` still doesn't work. I didn't figure out what's wrong with it.

How did I fix it? ...by passing the 2 parameters in the correct order -.-